# Is it possible to achieve this text-align-last shown in the image below using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an exam builder using a software that accepts pasted HTML and CSS into textboxes. The formatting I'm aiming for involves displaying exam statements with aligned statement numbers (I, II, III, IV) followed by the statements themselves. I want the numbers to align based on the last letter of the word, with a space between the number and the statement.

I've tried using `<p>**I** &emsp; Statement 1 </p>`, but this right-aligns the numbers instead of the left alignment shown in the picture. I also attempted using text-align-last, but it affects the entire item, not just the statement numbers.

Would placing the statements in their own container and aligning them afterwards be a better approach? I'm a design student, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  [image: expected results]

Comment: You should start with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a list and CSS counters if I were you. But you have to watch the `padding`:

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: counter;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 8px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: counter(counter, upper-roman);
  counter-increment: counter;
  width: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ansver 1</li>
  <li>Ansver 2</li>
  <li>Ansver 3</li>
  <li>Ansver 4</li>
</ul>
```

Or just use `list-style-type: upper-roman;`, but with the addition of a dot at the end of the character:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ansver 1</li>
  <li>Ansver 2</li>
  <li>Ansver 3</li>
  <li>Ansver 4</li>
</ul>
```